# Get certificate from server OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, raw-sockets

I am trying to develop an EAP-TLS client, using OpenSSL, raw sockets and C. I received a response from the server (FreeRADIUS) with a server_hello message. I now need to isolate the server certificates, server_key_exchange and certificate_request from the message. I currently have the packet in an uint8_t char[] array. Do I use the SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl) function? I figured I need to associate the earlier ssl context with the new packet. How do I go about this? Thank you!